# Регулярное выражение JS не работает

Tags: javascript

Всем ку! Помогите плез разобраться. Почему при следующем коде я получаю вывод 'ttps', а не 'facebook'? Почему не работает \?

```
var link = 'https://www.facebook.com/ultimatea.com.ua/?ref=settings';  
re = new RegExp('(?<=\.)[a-z]*');
var social = re.exec(link);
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

исправьте вторую строку на `re = new RegExp('(?<=\\.)[a-z]*');` и это сработает.
это связано с тем, что *"при передаче строки в new RegExp нужно удваивать обратную косую черту: \ для экранирования специальных символов, потому что строковые кавычки «съедят» одну черту."*